# Better way to write cascading if statements in Scala?

Tags: scala

In `JavaScript` we can rewrite:

```
if (ua.isEmpty()) {
    return false;
}
else if (ua.contains('curl')) {
    return false;
}
```

into this for clear code:

```
switch(true) {
    case ua.isEmpty():
        return false;
    case ua.contains('curl'):
        return false;
}
```

Any suggestion we could do things like this in Scala?

Comment: `if (ua.isEmpty || ua.contains("curl")) return false`

Comment: As this is an expression so using of `return` is not necessary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you care about is these two conditions you can just have some thing like this

```
if(ua.isEmpty || ua.contains('curl')) false
```

if you want to have more cases you can do something like this

```
   ua match{
     case _ if(ua.isEmpty) => false
     case _ if(ua.contains('curl') => false
     case _ => //return whatever you want if none of the above is true
    }
```

or with a traditional if else

```
if(ua.isEmpty)
 false
else if(ua.contains('curl')
 false
else 
 // return whatever you want
```

Notice that if you don't add the final `else` or the final `case _=>` then the return type will be `Any` and not `Boolean`

Answer (score 2):

As addition to Dionysis answer:

You can also use the `type` of the `object` you want to check - to make it more readable.

In your case if `ua` is a `List`:

```
ua match{
     case Nil => false
     case l if l.contains('curl') => false
     case _ => true
    }
```

As you see I also made some other small adjustments:

- parameters `()` in `if` are not needed
- I prefer to name the matched value and use this name in the `if`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Scala, I recommend using Options with ua `ua: Option[String]`.

```
val ua: Option[String] = // Some("String") or None
val result = ua match {
 case Some(x: String) if x.contains("curl") => false
 case Some(x) => // What you want
 case None => false
 case _ => // Error
}
```

If you want to use `if` you should use `ua: String` (not recommended).

```
val ua: String = // "String" or ""
val result = if (ua.contains('curl') || ua.isEmpty || ua != "") false else // What you want
```

You should not use `val ua: String = null` the answer is [here](https://medium.com/@anler/type-safe-scala-dont-use-null-3a1420b2a9d8)